# Questions about the repetition rate of papers?

Tags: extended-paper

One of my conference papers has been accepted but not yet indexed. I have uploaded it on arxiv. I wrote an extended version of the thesis. According to the requirements of the journal, the duplication rate with the original conference paper should be less than 30%. I used itenticate to check the duplicates. But now there are some problems that I don't quite understand.

1. First of all, the paper with the highest repetition rate did not declare which paper it was, but gave it to a website. How should I determine it?
2. I found that the papers I uploaded on arxiv did not show up in the list. But since I'm an extended dissertation, I have a few paragraphs of text that I haven't revised, why isn't this being found? I uploaded one last year.
3. How much do I need to reduce the overall repetition rate?
4. How can I do a duplication check with my conference paper? It's not indexed online yet, and I'm wondering if my revisions are over 70%.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The question(s) is(are) unclear to me. Please clarify more!

Comment: I have added some descriptions. Is there anything else unclear? Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to stop worrying about metrics and start worrying about writing a good scientific article that your readers are interested in.

Comment: I don't think this seems contradictory. It would be nice if you could convince the editor-in-chief of that journal not to care about specific metrics.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the paper with the highest repetition rate did not declare which paper it was, but gave it to a website". A paper is a passive object, it cannot declare anything by itself. *Someone*/*something* must declare something, but I don't understand what that is supposed to be.

Comment: For example, the two with the highest repetition rate shown in the picture. They don't point to specific papers, but to arxiv and a reading site.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the journal is only wanting to know if 30% of your text is the same as written in the conference article. I believe they want to know that the ideas/results you intend to present have not been published elsewhere.
Does the work you already have accepted contribute less than 30% of the content or meaning of the work?
This is probably not something you can measure using a comparison software, but something you need to reflect on yourself.

If the question you are asking is instead a technical question about the inner workings of the plagiarism software, ithenticate, please clarify that in the question.